# Architecting a configurable user notification service

Tags: service, notifications, cron, alert, jobs

I am building an application which needs to send notifications to users at a fixed time of day. Users can choose which time of day they would like to be notified, and which days they would like to be notified. For example, a user might like to be notified at 6am every day, or 7am only on week days.

On the back-end, I am unsure how to architect the service that sends these notifications. The solution needs to handle:

- concurrency, so I can scale my servers (notifications should not be duplicated)
- system restarts
- if a user changes their preferences, pending notifications should be rescheduled

Comment: In what manner will the users receive the notifications? Emails, Android/iOS push notifications, something else?

Comment: @robbat2 The type of notification should not really matter here. This is just about architecting a system that gives you a hook to do something asynchronous on a schedule. For the record, I will be sending web push notifications and/or emails.

Comment: You didn't specify platform/OS.

Comment: Any back end language and any database. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Using a message broker such as [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/) and task scheduler such as [Celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/master/index.html) may meet your requirements.

Asynchronous, or non-blocking, processing is a method of separating the execution of certain tasks from the main flow of a program. This provides you with several advantages, including allowing your user-facing code to run without interruption.

Message passing is a method which program components can use to communicate and exchange information. It can be implemented synchronously or asynchronously and can allow discrete processes to communicate without problems. Message passing is often implemented as an alternative to traditional databases for this type of usage because message queues often implement additional features, provide increased performance, and can reside completely in-memory.

Celery is a task queue that is built on an asynchronous message passing system. It can be used as a bucket where programming tasks can be dumped. The program that passed the task can continue to execute and function responsively, and then later on, it can poll celery to see if the computation is complete and retrieve the data.

While celery is written in Python, its protocol can be implemented in any language. worker is an implementation of Celery in Python. If the language has an AMQP client, there shouldn’t be much work to create a worker in your language. A Celery worker is just a program connecting to the broker to process messages.

Also, there’s another way to be language independent, and that’s to use REST tasks, instead of your tasks being functions, they’re URLs. With this information you can even create simple web servers that enable preloading of code. Simply expose an endpoint that performs an operation, and create a task that just performs an HTTP request to that endpoint.

Here it is the python example from official [documentation](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#entries):

```
from celery import Celery
from celery.schedules import crontab

app = Celery()

@app.on_after_configure.connect
def setup_periodic_tasks(sender, **kwargs):
    # Calls test('hello') every 10 seconds.
    sender.add_periodic_task(10.0, test.s('hello'), name='add every 10')

    # Calls test('world') every 30 seconds
    sender.add_periodic_task(30.0, test.s('world'), expires=10)

    # Executes every Monday morning at 7:30 a.m.
    sender.add_periodic_task(
        crontab(hour=7, minute=30, day_of_week=1),
        test.s('Happy Mondays!'),
    )

@app.task
def test(arg):
    print(arg)
```

Answer (score 0):

As I can see you need to have 3 types of entities: users (to store email or some other way to reach the user), notifications (to store what you want to send to user - text etc) and schedules (to store when user want to get notifications). You need to store entities of those types in some kind of database.
Schedule should be connected to user, notification should be connected to user and schedule.

Assume you have cron job that starts some script every minute. This script will try to get all notifications connected with schedule for current time (job starting time). Don't forget to implement some type of **overlaping prevention**.

After this script will place a tasks (with all needed data: type of notification, users who you want to notify etc) in queue (beanstalkd or something). You can create as many workers (even on different physical instances) as you want to serve this queue (without thinking about duplication) - this will give you a great **power of scalability**.

In case user changed his schedule it will affect all his notification at the same moment. There is no pending notification as they will be served only when they really should be send.

This is a very highlevel description. Many things depends on language, database(s), queue server, wokers implementation.